# Soldering WS2812B Daisy-Chain

Tags: led, soldering, ws2812b

I'm following this project. More specific Step 7: Rainbow Pistil

> https://www.instructables.com/Ever-Blooming-Mechanical-Tulip/

In the picture bellow. On the top left corner is how I should solder the leds.

1. The upper ring(Brass Wire) is the positive voltage
2. The lower ring(Brass Wire)

[image]

I am not sure if I should connect both 5V pin to the  positive voltage ( upper brass wire) and the two GND pins to the GND ( lower brass wire):

The other uncertainty is connecting the led lights daizy-chained. Can I use the middle OUT pin of one LED and connect it with the middle IN pin of the other LED.

I have tried to find a solution regarding this but there is no explanation  when it goes to connect them to a brass wire..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that the top picture shows just the LEDs, but the bottom picture shows little circuit boards (the LEDs are attached on the other side, not shown).

If you just have the LEDs (not attached to the little circuit boards), then you have four pins. GND, 5V, data in, data out. No problem.

The circuit boards have two 5V pads and two GND pads for easy daisy-chaining, but they're wired together on the circuit board. It doesn't matter which one you connect. You can connect both if you want to (e.g. for mechanical stability) but you don't have to.

Comment: thank you for you answer. I have it clear now that I do not need to solder both 5v and both gnd pins to the brass. Can I use the middle Out pin to connect to middle IN pin of the other LED?

Comment: @be1995 Yes, that is how the data has to be. You connect out->in out->in out->in etc. The first "in" comes from your controller (arduino or whatever) and the last "out" doesn't connect to anything. so arduino->in out->in out->in out->in out->in out->in out->in out->nothing